# setup problem for a publisher/subscriber running on different PCs

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri, baxter, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am really a ROS and Baxter beginner, and I am experiencing strange behaviour of the ROS communication layer that I do not understand.
Consider two trivial scripts, a publisher and a subscriber:

publisher.py:

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

pub = rospy.Publisher('foo', String)
rospy.init_node('publisher_test')
r = rospy.Rate(10)
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    pub.publish("hello world")
    r.sleep()
```

subscriber.py:

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo("I heard %s",data.data)

rospy.init_node('subscriber_test')
rospy.Subscriber("foo", String, callback)
rospy.spin()
```

The ROS_MASTER is running in the Baxter internal PC.

I have 4 different shell opened: two shells in my PC, both configured launching the script baxter.sh, and two SSH shells - both configured launching the script baxter.sh.
I have done 4 different experiment:

1. If I launch both the publisher and the subscriber from my PC, no problem arises.
2. If I launch both the publisher and the subscriber from the Baxter PC, no problem arises.
3. If I launch the publisher in from my PC and the subscriber from Baxter PC, no problem arises.
4. If I launch the publisher in the Baxter internal PC and the subscrber in my PC, the subscriber does not receive any message. If I launch "rostopic echo /foo" from my PC, it does not print anything. However, if I launch "/robot/joint_states" from my PC, no problem arises.

The PC and the baxter are direct connected with a twisted cable.

Some ideas?

Many thanks,

Sincerely
Nicola

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199131/setup-problem-for-a-publisher/subscriber-running-on-different-pcs/) by [Nicola Pedrocchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/21057/nicola-pedrocchi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably need to set the ROS_IP environment variable on Baxter.

For a more detailed explanation, check out my ROSCon talk from 2013: [slides](http://roscon.ros.org/2013/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Networking-for-ROS-Users.pdf) and [video](https://vimeo.com/67806888)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0